# How to automatically connect two objects(rectangles) on a window

Tags: java

So I have to create a project in java and I need steps on how to consider thinking about the problem.

Its a GUI related project. What is required is that there are two objects that a user would place on the screen window(imagine them like rectangles on the screen). 
And these rectangle objects have connector points. One point on the middle of each side of the rectangle(Hope that made sense).  And the user will choose one point in each rectangle and my program will have to find a path  between those two connector points. There could be obstacles like other rectangles between those two rectangles or walls.

So I am thinking I could use a path finding algorithm(like A*) to find a path between the two points but that's all I could figure out till now. 
I need help on how to think about this problem especially with the GUI part. 
Also the problem also requires that the number of turns be minimum. But I think I could work on that later. But if you've got an idea please share it here 
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: You'd be better off asking this question on hashnode as all answers you would receive here would be opinion based answers and stack overflow doesn't like such general questions as yours that wouldn't have a very specific answer.

Comment: @UncleIroh Okay thanks. I'll try asking there